array_contains() function wrongly interpretted with Spring boot?
I am having issue with Spring Boot, Hibernate and Postgres DB and I need some help working with array of strings.
I have an entity called MyEntity with following field:
@Column(name = "relations", columnDefinition = "text[]")
private Set<String> relations = new HashSet<>();

And I want to perform a query which will find all entities that contains at least one relation 'XXXX'. I am able to make it work with following query where I hard code the value:
@Query(value = """SELECT e.id FROM MyEntity e WHERE array_contains(e.relations, 'XXXXX')""")
List<String> findByRelation(String relation);

However when I start to use parameters like:
@Query(value = """SELECT e.id FROM MyEntity e WHERE array_contains(e.relations, :relation)""")
List<String> findByRelation(String relation);

It starts to fail with following error:
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: text[] @> character varying[]
      Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
      Position: 195

I think the problem is that combination of Spring-Boot and Hibernate interprets given relation parameter as array of characters instead of single string.
Can anyone advise how to fix/bypass this issue?


Where are you getting array_contains() from? That is not one of the builtin Postgres Array functions. 2) Are you maybe looking for ANY?


I am using function documented from here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-array-contains-functions

The document also says The following functions deal with SQL array types, which are not supported on every database.. What version of Postgres are you using?

I am having Postgres 15.4 and I can confirm that such function works. I was able to make it working using CriteriaQuery, but struggle to have it "simple" thought @Query and parameter

On my instance of Postgres 15: function array_contains() does not exist.  So either you are not connecting  to a stock install of Postgres or the ORM is doing some manipulation behind the scene.  I would tend to believe the latter, in which case this ERROR: operator does not exist: text[] @> character varying[] is the problem. As in select array['test', 'dog']::text[] @> array['dog']::varchar[]; operator does not exist: text[] @> character varying[]. In other words :relation is being cast to varchar[] and it needs to be text[].
